# CABasicAnimation doesn't work on 64bit device

Tags: ios, ios7, cabasicanimation, avassetexportsession

I want to add text to video so I follow this tutorial:
Ray's Tutorial - http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos
I only want my text to appear for first 5 seconds of the video so I added the following code:

```
     subtitleText.opacity=1.0;
     CABasicAnimation *animationMid = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [animationMid setDuration:Video.duration-5];
    [animationMid setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
    [animationMid setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
    [animationMid setBeginTime:5];
    [animationMid setFillMode:kCAFillModeRemoved];
    [subtitleText addAnimation:animationMid forKey:@"animationOpacity"];
```

Everything works perfectly on 32-bit simulator, iPhone 4, iPhone 4s but when I deploy on iPhone 5s or simulator 64bit the text doesn't disappear after 5 second in the video.

I've been searching but no document mentions this issue. Please help!

EDIT: 
I admit this code looks strange, but it does its job on iPhone 4/4S. At first, I wrote like this but it didn't work (on any device):

```
    subtitleText.opacity=1.0;
    CABasicAnimation *animationMid = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [animationMid setDuration:0.0];
    [animationMid setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
    [animationMid setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
    [animationMid setBeginTime:5];
    [animationMid setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [subtitleText addAnimation:animationMid forKey:@"animationOpacity"];
```

Comment: That's a strange looking animation. For example, the `toValue` and `fromValue` are the same. Also, the beginTime should be `CACurrentMediaTime + theDelay`.

Comment: I've just added `[animationMid setBeginTime: CACurrentMediaTime +5];` but no luck. Also see my edit for explanation about strange code

Answer (score -1):

This is an odd way to achieve what you want. Instead having a 5sec long animation, you have an animation which runs nearly the entire length of the video. Creative nonetheless, but you are not animating things at all - what you want is hide the text after 5sec.

Why not just call a block after 5sec delay?

```
subtitleText.opacity = 1.0;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    subtitleText.opacity = 0.0;
});
```

Comment: This is a _very_ bad way of calling code after an animation finishes!

Comment: Please explain? Because there is no animation going on.

Comment: The OP is using a CABasicAnimation

Comment: My answer suggests replacing the whole animation. There is no animation going on in my answer.